# Can't append multiple object to a list type dictionnary value

Tags: python, structure

im hitting a wall and im slowly falling into despair.

I have the following structure ( let's call this event_dict ):

```
{
  'ABC123':[],
  'ABC234':[],
  'ABC444':[]
}
```

and something like this ( let's call this one event_list ) :

```
[
  {'code':ABC123, 'data':'some data' },
  {'code':ABC234, 'data':'some data' }
  {'code':ABC234, 'data':'some data' }
]
```

Im trying to push the data in event list in my event dict. I'm using the event_list['code'] to determine which event have to be appended in the event_dict, based on it's keys.

Here's the code i wrote :

```
for event in event_list :


  /* some processing here */

  for motherEvent in event_dict :
    if motherEvent.keys()[0] == event['code']:
      event_dict[motherEvent.keys()[0]].append(event)

      /* also tried this :
      motherEvent.append(event) and got : 
      list indices must be integers, not dict */
```

But i got this error : `list indices must be integers, not unicode`

There's something i'm not getting but i don't see what.\

Is there a better approach ? Im just trying to group a list of dicts, inside a higher struct, based on their `'code'`.

Comment: Don't use C-style comments in your Python code. Use *Python comments*.

Comment: Head's up, the following: `motherEvent.keys()[0]` will not always give you what you intend. Dictionaries are *unordered* data-structures.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the data you provided:

```
event_dict = {
    'ABC123':[],
    'ABC234':[],
    'ABC444':[]}

event_list = [
    {'code': 'ABC123', 'data':'some data' },
    {'code': 'ABC234', 'data':'some data' },
    {'code': 'ABC234', 'data':'some data' }]
```

You can do something like:

```
for el in event_list:
    event_dict[el['code']].append(el['data'])
```

You'll get the following result:

```
{'ABC123': ['some data'], 'ABC444': [], 'ABC234': ['some data', 'some data']}
```

No need to nest your for loops. Try to avoid nesting loops if you can.

Comment: I need to check if the event_dict key match with the event_list['code'], so i dont have a choice to loop into those 2 structs. 

i've edited my post a bit before your comment so i believe you haven't seen it, but this code give me the error : list indices must be integers, not dict

Comment: You don't need to check if the key is already doing that for you. " I'm using the event_list['code'] to determine which event have to be appended in the event_dict, based on it's keys." <---- this is what the above is doing.

Comment: You don't need an if statement, if it throws then handle it! Do you have an else clause incase it doesn't match? what benefit is there to including an if statement? I'm curious, maybe there's something I'm missing? and the values of `event_list` needs to be a string and you're missing a comma.